# Is it a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

We are considering a transformation $f: E^2 \rightarrow E^2$. I need to determine if f is linear and if so, I need to describe its null space and range, and compute its nullity and rank.

$f$ is defined such that it maps each point $(x,y)$ onto its reflection with respect to a fixed line through the origin.

I think I know how to show that is a linear transformation, however, I am having trouble expressing $f(x,y)=\space ?$

Can someone just express for me $f(x,y)$ and explain to me why it has this expression. I can continue from there.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: choose co-ordinates carefully.

Comment: If it is linear, you need only work out the behaviour on a basis. Try $(1,0)^T, (0,1)^T$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. What is $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$

Comment: @user43418, those are column vectors...

Comment: Oh ok so its f(x,y)=(0,1) right ?

Comment: Try reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_across_a_line_in_the_plane , or also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306838/algorithm-for-reflecting-a-point-across-a-line

Comment: Figure out what $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ are.

Comment: According to DonAntonio's links I considered a line y=ax and I set $d=\frac{x+ay}{1+a^2} $

Therefore I obtain: f(x,y)=(2d-x,2ad-y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r$ be the line whith respect to which you're making the reflection. Simple choose a non-zero vector $v$ that spawns $r$ (for example, if $r$ is given by some equation $r=\left\{(x,y)\in E^2: ax+by=0\right\}$, with $a^2+b^2\neq 0$, then you can choose $v=(-b,a)$)

Now you should be convinced that:

(1) The points of $r$ are fixed by $f$, so $f(v)=v$.

(2) if $w$ is perpendicular to $r$, then $f(w)=-w$.

Now, let $v=(a,b)$, a non-zero vector spanning $r$, and $w=(-b,a)$, which is perpendicular to $v$, and hence is perpendicular to $r$. From (1) and (2) above, and by linearity of $f$, you have the system of equations:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
  af(1,0)+bf(0,1)=(a,b)\\
  -bf(1,0)+af(0,1)=(b,-a)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

It's easy to solve that system for $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$, giving you the solutions $f(1,0)=\dfrac{(a-b,b+a)}{a^2+b^2} $and $f(0,1)=\dfrac{(a+b,b-a)}{a^2+b^2}$.

Now to have a formula for $f$, you can use linearity again and expand
$f(x,y)=xf(1,0)+yf(0,1)$.

Comment: It should be f(x,y)=xf(1,0)+yf(0,1) no?

Comment: So we get: $f(x,y)=\frac{((a-b)x+(a+b)y,(a+b)x+(b-a)y)}{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: the expression is correct right ?

Comment: In addition to that, I just wanted to check the answers for the final question.

I foud Ker(f)={(0,0)}, the range is $\mathbb{R}^2$, the nullity and rank of T are both equal to 2

Comment: The nullity is $dim(Ker(f))=0$ and the rank is $dim(f(\mathbb{R}^2))=dim\mathbb{R}^2=2$...

Comment: You are right because dim(Ker(f))=dim(E^2)-dim(Im(f))=2-2=0